# S3 CreateEventSourceMapping triggers "Operation not found" error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm trying to create source maps so when someone uploads something inside the bucket, Lambda will trigger a previously created function, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html)

But, when I call this:

```
$fnName = 'my_function';
$s3->createEventSourceMapping([
    //'BatchSize' => <integer>,
    'Enabled' => true, //<boolean>
    'EventSourceArn' => 'arn:aws:s3:::'.S3_BUCKET.'/'.$fnName, // REQUIRED
    'FunctionName' => $fnName, // REQUIRED
    'StartingPosition' => 'LATEST', //'TRIM_HORIZON|LATEST|AT_TIMESTAMP',
    //'StartingPositionTimestamp' => <integer || string || DateTime>,
]);
```

I get the following error message `Operation not found: CreateEventSourceMapping`.

Some of those parameters are not active because according to the documentation found in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-lambda-2015-03-31.html#createeventsourcemapping they have default values or aren't required (as far as I undestand)

At the moment I am using PHP SDK (ver 3.94.2). Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [createEventSourceMapping()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-lambda-2015-03-31.html#createeventsourcemapping) method is a method on a [Lambda client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Lambda.LambdaClient.html), not on an S3 client.

Comment: Oh gosh... shame on me hahaha